# Who names Starships?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship

Following on from [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53637/who-names-starship-classes) question comes the following question: who is responsible for naming *starships* eg who gave the name 'Enterprise' to the series of ships bearing that name?  (In-universe answers only please.)

Comment: I don't believe there is an in universe answer to who actually names the Ships, it's most likely Starfleet though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as we know the people who name the ships are most likely Starfleet, I really doubt there's anywhere showing who actually named the ships.  The only info that we have is the fact that most ship's name has an origin of some sort.

[There's a list here.](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/name_origins1.htm)

Examples being such as:

- USS Adelphi (Adelphi meaning the plural version of the greek word
  Adelphos, which means brother)
- USS Albert Einstein (named after the famous scientist)
- USS Apollo (named after the famous moon landing shuttle and the greek god of light)

Answer (score 2):

Chief of Starfleet Operations gave special dispensation to rename the USS Sao Paulo after the original Defiant was destroyed. Presumably they are responsible for naming new ships also. They probably have a big list of names to use, and assign them accordingly as a ship is being designed.

http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Defiant_(2375)